# Django taggit app not working.Tag names for filtering not being rendered

Tags: html, django, jinja2

i am trying to create a blog which shows posts according to selected tags.I've got half of it working as the tags are being displayed on the posts.But the option to filter posts will not appear.
my views.py:-

```
def post_list(request,tag_slug=None):
    object_list=UserPost.published.all()
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
#paginationstart
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # Show 25 contacts per page.

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render(request,'post/list.html',{'posts':posts,'page':page,'tag':tag})
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/',views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
        path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,
         name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:post_id>/share/',
         views.post_share, name='post_share'),
```

My template:

```
{% if tag %}
  <h2>Posts tagged with "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
{% endif %}

<p class="tags">
  Tags:
  {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
    <a href="{% url "/blog/post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
      {{ tag.name }}
    </a>
    {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</p>
```

i have added TaggableManager to models.The 'tags' element in the  'p' tags are being rendered after the title.But the tag names from the for loop are not being rendered.

my models.py

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
    ('draft','Draft'),
    ('published','Published'),
    )
    title= models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish',null=True)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_post')
    body= models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
    tags=TaggableManager()
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.month,
                             self.publish.day, self.slug])




    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can you please share the models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem done sir.